# Open generated Pdf file in browser Play Framework(Scala)

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1, pdfbox

i used PDFBOX in my Scala code to generate pdf file ,now i'm storing the generated file in server with following code

```
doc.save(new File(".").getAbsolutePath()+"/report.pdf")
```

how to open pdf file in browser after it generated rather than storing?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have to return your file content in response with MIME type set to `application/pdf`.

Answer (score 0):

[Official Document](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.3/ScalaStream) suggests to use Ok.sendFile with inline = true. Play will try to find out proper MIME type for you.

```
def index = Action {
  Ok.sendFile(
    content = new java.io.File("/tmp/fileToServe.pdf"),
    inline = true
  )
}
```